Refernce to RouteValueDictionary claims it is defined in System.Web but could not be found
I am currently learning to unit test in ASP.NET MVC, and I have encountered an issue while working on my Controller Test class. The error message states, "Reference to RouteValueDictionary claims it is defined in System.Web but could not be found." This error arises when I try to use RouteValueDictionary in my test class. Despite including the necessary System.Web and System.Web.Routing namespaces, the error persists. It seems the reference to RouteValueDictionary is not being recognized correctly in my test project. This issue is hindering my progress in writing effective unit tests for my ASP.NET MVC application.
using Resource_Management.Interface;
using Resource_Management.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AccountControllerTest
{
    public class AccountControllerTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Register_ValidUser_ShouldRedirectToLogin()
        {
            // Arrange
            var mockUserServices = new Mock<IUserServices>();
            var controller = new AccountController(mockUserServices.Object);
            var loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel
            {
                Username = "newUser",
                Password = "newPassword"
            };

            // Act
            var result = controller.Register(loginViewModel) as RedirectToRouteResult;

            // Assert
            Assert.NotNull(result);
            Assert.Equal("Login", result.RouteValues["action"]);
            Assert.Equal("Account", result.RouteValues["controller"]);
            mockUserServices.Verify(s => s.RegisterUser(It.Is<User>(u => u.Username == "newUser" && u.Password == "newPassword")), Times.Once());
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Register_InvalidUser_ShouldReturnViewWithModel()
        {
            // Arrange
            var mockUserServices = new Mock<IUserServices>();
            var controller = new AccountController(mockUserServices.Object);
            controller.ModelState.AddModelError("error", "some error");
            var loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel
            {
                Username = "newUser",
                Password = "newPassword"
            };

            // Act
            var result = controller.Register(loginViewModel) as ViewResult;

            // Assert
            Assert.NotNull(result);
            Assert.Equal(loginViewModel, result.Model);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Login_ValidUser_ShouldRedirectToHome()
        {
            // Arrange
            var mockUserServices = new Mock<IUserServices>();
            mockUserServices.Setup(s => s.ValidateUser("validUser", "validPassword")).Returns(true);
            mockUserServices.Setup(s => s.GetUserByUsername("validUser")).Returns(new User { Username = "validUser" });

            var controller = new AccountController(mockUserServices.Object);

            // Act
            var result = controller.Login("validUser", "validPassword") as RedirectToRouteResult;

            // Assert
            Assert.NotNull(result);

            Assert.Equal("Index", result.RouteValues["action"]);
            Assert.Equal("Home", result.RouteValues["controller"]);
            Assert.Equal("validUser", ((User)controller.Session["User"]).Username);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Login_InvalidUser_ShouldReturnViewWithError()
        {
            // Arrange
            var mockUserServices = new Mock<IUserServices>();
            mockUserServices.Setup(s => s.ValidateUser("invalidUser", "invalidPassword")).Returns(false);

            var controller = new AccountController(mockUserServices.Object);

            // Act
            var result = controller.Login("invalidUser", "invalidPassword") as ViewResult;

            // Assert
            Assert.NotNull(result);
            Assert.True(controller.ModelState.ContainsKey(""));
            Assert.Equal("Invalid username or password", controller.ModelState[""].Errors[0].ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}

I have tried updating the packages and ensuring they are restored correctly, but the error remains unresolved. Additionally, I attempted changing the target framework of my project to ensure compatibility, but this did not fix the issue either. The error message "Reference to RouteValueDictionary claims it is defined in System.Web but could not be found" continues to appear in my Controller Test class. Despite these efforts, I am still unable to resolve the problem and proceed with my unit testing in ASP.NET MVC. This issue is currently blocking my progress and I am seeking a solution to overcome it.

This sounds like some kind of project/solution configuration issue, rather than an issue with the test code per se. It's hard to tell from here, though. Your best chance is to try to reduce the problem to a minimal reproducible example (MRE), in which case you're likely to solve the problem by yourself, but otherwise, please edit the post so that it provides an MRE.
